# How to add movie to timeline and start in middle of movie

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I am a complete newb with Blender, so please bear with me. I am trying to do some basic color correction/grading on drone footage, but in some cases I want to be able to insert a movie and start at, for example, 60 frames in. How do I do that? When I change the start frame for the movie, it just moves it forward in the timeline. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below the *Edit Strip* tab, where you had set the *Start Frame*, there is the *Strip Input* tab.

If you want the strip to actually display a later frame on your frame 1, change the **Start** property below **Trim Duration (hard)** to your desired start frame of the clip.

[image: start frame property]

Another more manual way of doing this.

1. Scrub forward to or pause on your desired start frame.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to cut the clip into two.
3. Select the first (now redundant) clip and delete it by pressing <kbd>X</kbd>.
4. Select the clip which now starts on your desired frame and move it backwards to the start of the scene by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> and then dragging the mouse. Once in grab mode, you can also enter an offset (like "-60") with the keyboard.

Reference: [Blender Manual Entry](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/editors/sequencer/usage.html#moving-and-modifying-strips)